# Where to store a props type declaration on a DDD project?

Tags: domain-driven-design, interfaces, front-end, vue.js

I am trying to apply DDD to a Vue project (so it's DDD on the frontend) and I have a doubt as to where store a props type. A Vue component can have `props`, which is basically named data passed to the component. Most of my components that work as a page are stored inside the `application` folder, because they manage all the data flux, that is, the repositories that make API calls, instanciating domain classes, etc. For each of these `application` components, I have a `.ts` file that speciafies its props; so together with my `Profile.vue`, I have a `ProfileProps.ts`.

`Profile.vue`: the props being defined

```
import type { ProfileProps } from './ProfileProps'

const props = defineProps<ProfileProps>()
```

The props type inside `ProfileProps.ts`

```
export type ProfileProps = {
  user: IBackendUser
}
```

As you can see, there's only one prop and it's also typed as what I expect the backend to pass to my component: the user. My question is, where should I keep this interface of mine `IBackendUser`: maybe a folder in the application called `interfaces`, or maybe put it in the `domain` folder?

PS.: I have a separate file for the props because some components have extense props (big objects), and I want to keep the pattern for all the project.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- **Domain Layer**: If `IBackendUser` is a core domain concept, put it in the `domain` folder.
- **Application Layer**: If it's specific to the application logic, place it in an `interfaces` subfolder within the `application` folder.
- **Component-Specific**: If it's only used in the `Profile` component, you could keep it in the same folder as `Profile`.
- **Shared Types**: If used across layers, consider a `shared` or `common` folder.

Choose based on where the type is most relevant and keep your approach consistent across the project.